# Structure of winget source repositories

Tags: windows, cmd, package-managers, winget

Microsoft announced and open-sourced [winget](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli), a package manager for Windows.

When entering `winget source` (after installing it), it can be seen that it supports adding sources.

`winget source` provides the following subcommands:

```
add     Add a new source
list    list current sources
update  updates current sources
remove  removes current sources
reset   resets sources
```

By entering `winget source list`, the default source is displayed (as long as the sources were not changed):

```
C:\Windows\System32>winget source list
Name   Arg
-----------------------------------------
winget https://winget.azureedge.net/cache
```

As sources can be added using `winget source add`, how can source repositories be created?

How does a repository has to be structured or is there just not enough documentation to answer this question?

---

<sub>I think this question is on-topic for Stack Overflow as the main reason to add sources is (in my point of view) to create alpha/beta channels for programs or similar.</sub>

Comment: This could help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/package/repository. And for custom repo it says "There are currently no known third party repositories. Microsoft is working with multiple partners to develop protocols or an API to enable third party repositories."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

winget 1.0 [introduced a new REST API](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-package-manager-1-0/) for custom repositories. The API and a reference implementation are provided by Microsoft at [github.com/microsoft/winget-cli-restsource/](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli-restsource/). The reference implementation uses C# and allows self-hosting on Azure. Hosted offerings are also becoming available, such as https://winget.pro.

Before winget 1.0, the structure of winget repositories looked roughly as follows:

1. The remote repository should have a `source.msix` file. You may refer to the example at the default repository: https://winget.azureedge.net/cache/source.msix
2. One can find details about MSIX itself on the [Microsoft Docs website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/overview).
3. Actually the `source.msix` is a zip package with contents structured in a pre-defined fashion (just rename it to `source.zip` and unpack):

   - `Assets/`
   - `Public/`
   - `AppxBlockMap.xml`
   - `AppxManifest.xml`
   - `AppcSignature.p7x`
   - `[Content_Typex.xml]`
4. The main data file seems to be `Public/index.db`. It is an SQLite database containing information derived from [Community Repo Manifests](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-pkgs/tree/master/manifests). It has a quite simple structure to understand.
5. Another concern is the MSIX should be signed by the developer. One should change Windows settings in order `winget` to accept packages signed by third parties. See below for details.
6. Note that `winget` doesn't accept an HTTP repository, it requires only the HTTPS one with a trusted certificate.
7. The most interesting tables in `index.db` are `manifest` and `pathparts`. The first matches application's name, version, etc. to pathparts, and the latter points to the manifest YAML-file.

   For example: https://winget.azureedge.net/cache/manifests/RubyInstallerTeam/Ruby/e70d-2.7.2.yaml (a cache of [github/winget-pkgs/manifests/RubyInstallerTeam/Ruby/2.7.2.yaml](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-pkgs/blob/master/manifests/RubyInstallerTeam/Ruby/2.7.2.yaml)).
8. `winget` uses this cached manifest for application installation.
9. In order `winget` could add the third-party source repository (when the `source.msix` signed by third-party certificate) one should allow installing sideload apps.

[image: Windows Settings]

10. Summarizing the above the overall sequence seems to be the following:

    - Download the `source.msix` from the `winget`'s default repo: https://winget.azureedge.net/cache/source.msix
    - Unpack it as a ZIP-package or using the [MSIX Packaging Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/tool-overview) to get the `index.db` file from `Public` directory.
    - Edit this SQLite DB (I've used the [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) for that) leaving only your application (tables `ids`, `monikers`, `names`, `versions`).
    - Set the path to YAML-manifest in `pathparts` table (one record per each path element). E.g. for `/manifests/MyCompany/MyProduct/1.0.0.yaml` the table should be like:
      [image: pathparts table example]
    - Edit the `manifest` table by adding the record that unites all related records.
    - Save the edited `index.db`, overwrite it in `source.msix` using the MSIX Packaging Tool, sign the MSIX with your own code-signing certificate.
    - Upload both the manifest (see [Manifest Specification](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/blob/master/doc/ManifestSpecv0.1.md) for details about manifest itself) and `source.msix` to your server (e.g. to `myserver.net/repo/source.msix` and `myserver.net/repo/manifests/MyCompany/MyProduct/1.0.0.yaml`).
    - Use:

    ```
    winget source add myrepo https://myserver.net/repo
    winget install MyProduct
    ```

Comment: Note for debugging: directories seem to work as sources, too (even without `file://`)

Comment: Also, it seems that the URL is neither contained and the sqlite database nor in any other file in the msix package.

Comment: If you don't find the `index.db` inside the `source.msix`, you are just to rename it to `source.zip` and unpack.

Comment: Yes, I found it and I saw the structure but I think there are files beside the `source.msix`

Comment: Exactly, DB records (`pathparts` particularly) point to YAML-manifests cached on the server. Please see an update in the post.

Comment: @Shamil thank you for answer. i can access to yaml file but i could not see installation parameters (silent install paramaters) in yaml file or in database. How do we find silent insall parameters ?

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy a private REST source to Azure using the [reference implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli-restsource).

It is also possible to create your own implementation referencing the [Swagger API](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli-restsource/tree/main/documentation).

Answer (score 2):

WinGet 1.0 has [just been released](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-package-manager-1-0/), and Microsoft has also released a reference implementation of the REST API source so it’s possible to host your own private repository.
It's called WinGet.RestSource and can be [cloned from here](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli-restsource); because it’s an Azure solution, next to Visual Studio 2019 you also need an Azure subscription.

I found that getting WinGet.RestSource up and running and pushing packages to it (currently) isn't *that* easy, but for anyone who's interested, I've written 2 blog posts about this:

- [Hosting your own WinGet private repository](https://blogs.infosupport.com/hosting-your-own-winget-private-repository/)
- [Adding a package to your private WinGet.RestSource feed using its API](https://blogs.infosupport.com/adding-a-package-to-your-private-winget-restsource-feed-using-its-api/)

Answer (score 1):

As of July 2020, as clarified by [How to Update Winget Source List](https://allthings.how/how-to-update-winget-source-list/):

> Winget is a really young application in terms of software age and currently, only has a single source/repo available for it, Microsoft's official Winget repository.
>
> *Thus sub-commands such as `add` and `remove` aren't of use yet.*